# Failed load delimited layer in QGIS python console

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm trying to follow the map rendering section from the PyQGIS cookbook. I am able to render a shapefile using qgs vector layer, however getting error prompt while loading delimited text file through qgs vector layer.

[image]

My script is (running in QGIS python console)

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtXml import *

mapinstance = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()
mapinstance.removeAllMapLayers()

layer = QgsVectorLayer("f:\scripts\map\wb.shp", "wb", "ogr")

if layer.isValid():
    print "shape layer successfully loaded - adding to map instance"
    mapinstance.addMapLayer(layer)
else:
    print "shape layer failed to load!" 

uri = "f:/scripts/map/points.csv?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (",", "longitude", "latitude")
vlayer=QgsVectorLayer(uri,"points","delimitedtext")

if vlayer.isValid():
    print "point layer successfully loaded - adding to map instance"
    mapinstance.addMapLayer(vlayer)
else:
    print "point layer failed to load!"


print mapinstance.mapLayers()
# create image
img = QImage(QSize(800,600), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
# set image background color
color = QColor(255,255,255)
img.fill(color.rgb())
# create painter
p = QPainter()
p.begin(img)
p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
render = QgsMapRenderer()
# set layer set
lst = [ layer.id() ] # add ID of every layer
render.setLayerSet(lst)
# set extent
rect = QgsRectangle(render.fullExtent())
#rect.scale(1.39800703)
rect.scale(1.1)
render.setExtent(rect)
# set output size
render.setOutputSize(img.size(), img.logicalDpiX())
# do the rendering
render.render(p)
p.end()

# save image
img.save('f:\scripts\out.png',"png")
```

and points.csv file contains following data

```
longitude,latitude

88.3697222,22.5697222

87.3194986,22.3243243
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to write the url that points to the csv as such:

```
uri =  "file:///f:/scripts/map/points.csv?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (",", "longitude", "latitude")
```